# sas + formatting macro variable result created using proc sql select into:

Tags: sas

I use code to write tables that captures the total count for each column as a macro variable, then uses it in the labels statement to complete the table column headers.

The count cohort&cnum._tot is created as:

```
 proc sql noprint;
     select count(*) into : cohort&cnum._tot from &analytic_file. (&&cohort&cnum);
 quit;
```

And is used:

```
 proc print data=TABLES.&tbl noobs label split="*";
      var label_
           c1_STAT1  c2_STAT1 c12_stat
           c3_STAT1  c4_STAT1 c34_stat
           c5_STAT1  c6_STAT1 c56_stat     ;
    * labeling step creates column header detail ;
      label
           %do i=1 %to &num;
               c&i._STAT1 = "&&&c&i.lab. * N= &&cohort&i._tot. * N"
           %end;
           c12_stat = "* * * % of row" 
           c34_stat = "* * * % of row"
           c56_stat = "* * * % of row"
           ;
 run;
```

I've looked around and can't find a solution ... so I'm here asking is there a way to format  **&&cohort&i._tot.** so that it returns 8,675,309 instead of 8675309?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the format in your `proc sql` using `format=comma12.`

Your code would be like this:

```
 proc sql noprint;
     select count(*) format=comma12. into : cohort&cnum._tot from &analytic_file. (&&cohort&cnum);
 quit;
```

Comment: Perfecto! Thanks so much.  I love an answer that should've been right under my nose :)

Comment: It happens to the best of us. Please approve if you are satisfied with my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can format the `count(*)` in the `select` by using the `PUT` function.  In this example the row count is multiplied to get a number large enough to require commas.  The **TRIMMED** option removes leading and trailing spaces from the value before sticking it into the macro variable.

```
proc sql noprint;
  select put( 123456789 * count(*),comma18.-L) into :count trimmed from sashelp.class;

  %put !&count.!;
```

The alternative is to format the macro value using `sysfunc`. Two ways, either works.

```
%put %sysfunc(sum(&count.), comma12.);   %* format feature of sysfunc evaluation;
%put %sysfunc(putn(&count , comma12.));  %* versus putn function;
```